# How do you constantly keep adding a number to a variable while the program is running

Tags: python

Recently, I've been developing something and have been wondering how I would constantly keep adding a number to a variable.

For example,

```
vel = 5

if vel < 1000:
    vel += 1
print(vel)
```

How would I make it so it would constantly keep adding 1 to the variable vel?

Thanks, I could literally not find this answer anywhere.

Comment: `while True: vel += 1`?

Comment: What you're after is a technique called "looping". The two main ways you can "loop" in Python is using `for` loops, or `while` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `if` statement, use `while` loops instead.

```
vel = 5

while vel < 1000:
    vel += 1
print(vel)
```